# Auto increment input box id when dynamically delete the table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to dynamically create and delete the row of a table, but I need that when I delete the row then the Id of input field should be in sequential order.
Suppose I have created a row and the id of "Item no" is 1 and again I created another row then the next id of "Item no" will be 2 and vice versa. But the case is that when we delete the "item no" of 5th id then the 6th id will be automatically change into 5th.

I have written the code of dynamically created and deleted the row but I need help for auto increment the id.

```
<table class="table table-hover poTable">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th class="col-md-1">
        Item No.
     </th>
     <th class="col-md-1">
        Fruit Code
     </th>
     <th>
        Fruit Name
     </th>
     <th>
        Unit Price
     </th>
     <th>
        UOM
     </th>
     <th>
        Order Quantity
     </th>
     <th>
        Amount
     </th>
     <th>
        Action
     </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableBody">
<!-- row -->
<tr class="first">
   <td>
     <input type="text" id="itemNo1" class="form-control" name="itemNumber"  value="10">
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control required" id="fruitCode1"  >
    <option>100</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="fruitName1"  class="form-control required"  name="fName" value="mango">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="unitPrice1"  class="form-control required"   name="uPrice" value="100">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="uom1" class="form-control required"  name="uOM" value="kg">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="qty1" name="tQTY" class="form-control required " onchange="totalAmount();">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="total1" name="tPrice" class="form-control tAmountMain required" disabled>
   </td>
   <td>
     <p onclick="createTable();" style="cursor:pointer">Create</p>
   </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now, here is my js code.

```
var counter= 1;
function createTable(){

counter++;

var itemNo = document.getElementById("itemNo1").value;
var fruitCode = document.getElementById("fruitCode1").value;
var fruitName = document.getElementById("fruitName1").value;
var unitPrice = document.getElementById("unitPrice1").value;
var uom = document.getElementById("uom1").value;
var qty = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
var amount = document.getElementById("total1").value;




$('#totalRowCount').text(counter-1);
var htmlText = '';
htmlText += '<tr class="first">';
htmlText += '<td class="itemNumber">';
htmlText += '<input type="text" id="itemNo'+counter+'" class="form-control" name="itemNumber" value="'+itemNo+'">' ;
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '<td>';
htmlText += '<select class="form-control" disabled  id="fruitCode'+counter+'">';
htmlText += '<option>'+fruitCode+'</option>';
htmlText += '</select>';
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '<td class="itemNumber">';
htmlText += '<input type="text" id="fruitName'+counter+'" class="form-control" name="itemNumber" disabled value="'+fruitName+'">' ;
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '<td class="itemNumber">';
htmlText += '<input type="text" id="unitPrice'+counter+'" class="form-control" name="itemNumber" disabled value="'+unitPrice+'">' ;
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '<td class="itemNumber">';
htmlText += '<input type="text" id="uom'+counter+'" class="form-control" name="itemNumber" disabled value="'+uom+'">' ;
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '<td class="itemNumber">';
htmlText += '<input type="text" id="qty'+counter+'" class="form-control" name="itemNumber" value="'+qty+'">' ;
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '<td class="itemNumber">';
htmlText += '<input type="text" id="total'+counter+'" class="form-control tAmount" name="itemNumber"  value="'+amount+'">' ;
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '<td class="itemNumber">';
htmlText += ' <i class="icon-minus icon-2x minusIcon del" onclick="deleteRows();"></i>' ;
htmlText += '</td>';
htmlText += '</tr>';
htmlText += '</tbody>';
htmlText += '</table>';

$('#tableBody').append(htmlText);
var sum = 0;
$('.tAmount').each(function() {
sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
$('#grandTotal').val(sum)
}

function deleteRows(){

$('.del').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      var sum = 0;
$('.tAmount').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
$('#grandTotal').val(sum)
});

}
```

Comment: You could grab all the items each time delete something and reset their IDs so that they are sequential. Also, I'd consider using a library to help you do this. Something like jQuery, or even Angular.

Comment: @Sam  this id is also used on other controls like unitPrice,total. You don't want to update that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recoment you to introduce an attribute to the **<tr>** element like row-number="1", row-number="2" like that because your text box is editable and then you can write a function to update the row number always for create and delete

```
htmlText += '<tr class="first" row-number="' + counter +'">';
.....
.....
window.updateIds = function() {
    $.each($("[row-number]"), function(index, item){
        $(this).attr("row-number",(index+1));
        $("[id^=itemNo]", $(this)).attr("id", "itemNo"+(index+1));
    });
}
```

Call this function after you last line in both create and delete

```
$('#grandTotal').val(sum);
updateIds();
```

Check my JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/37tmwLev/

--EDIT--

To update the **ID** attribute you have to use the attribute starts with selector https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$("[id^=itemNo]", $(this)).attr("id", "itemNo"+(index+1));
```

Check this JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/37tmwLev/1/

You don't have to maintain the total rows, you can get the number of rows with the code

```
var counter = $("[row-number]").length+1;
```

(or)

```
var counter = $("poTable tr").length+1;
```

Comment: This code is not working. It gives the same output as my code gives

Comment: I don't need to update the row number, I just need to update the texbox id.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zigma Empire. You save my time.

Answer (score 0):

You can recalculate the counter every time you delete a row:

```
var recalculate = function() {
   $('table.poTable').find('tbody > tr').each(function(index) {
      var newCount = index + 1;
      $(this).find('[id^=itemNo]').attr('id','itemNo' + newCount);
   });
}

$('.del').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   recalculate();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kapantzak, but there is one problem that when we deleting the row then it gives right output but when we add another row then the id will be from last index, and when we delete a row again than it will be in sequential